# Use headers or POST data to pass HTTP auth tokens?

Tags: rest, http, http-headers, authorization

When designing an HTTP API, is there any reason why we should choose one method over the other:

- pass the auth token in headers
- pass the auth token in POST data?

I can see why passing it in the query has disadvantages: URLs can be logged client side or server side. Are there similar side effects that apply to passing the token in a header or POST data? I'm trying to decide between the 2.

Comment: The URL logging consideration is also the main one that comes to mind. Even more than client and server, I'd be concerned about proxies - even assuming your authentication happens over HTTPs, some corporate environments would do SSL man-in-the-middle and still see the URL.
URL might be also more susceptible to unwanted logins, whereby someone refreshes the browser and generates a new login request; browsers do not re-submit POST content automatically. (Of course, please ignore that if you have a pure API that has nothing to do with browsers).
No special considerations for POSTs come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's better to use headers to pass auth tokens. The most important argument, I think, is that you can see the tokens in browser and if you use HTTPS, they will also be visible (only the payload is encrypted).

That said, I think that you should leverage existing authentication mechanism / header provided by HTTP:

- For example, the header `Authorization` - see the RFC 2617: 
  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt
- This link could also give you some hints about implementation of authentication within a RESTful service - see https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/

Hope this helps you,
Thierry